# Nested for Loop in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{% for i in some_dict %}
    {% for value in some_dict.i %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

as i understended python try to find value with 'i' key, but i want to find value with the key that contains in i

Сan i make something like this? How if i can?

Maybe there is another more correct way for unpucking dicts?

Dict example:
{a: [val1, val2, val3],
b: [val1, val2, val3]}

Comment: I don't understand what "value with the key that contains in i" means.  Can you use that example data to say what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant getting all the values in i?
You have a dictionary whose keys are strings and values are list? So you want to loop through all keys and values in the list?
Something like this?

```
{% for key, values_list in some_dict.items %}
   <b> {{ key }} </b>
   {% for value in values_list %}
      {{ value }} <br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will output the keys of the dictionary and the values in those lists.